# Program stops working when function is called.

Tags: c++

There is a problem somewhere in this function, unfortunately compiler doesnt says where. Program just stops working and it has to be shut down.

I am a begginer in c++ so I maz have done something stupid but i dont know what.

I will apreciate any help.

```
vector< vector<string> >gsiread16::make_section(vector<string> blocks) {

string code;
string code2;
vector<string> section;
vector< vector<string> > sections;

for ( int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {

    code = blocks[ i ].substr(0,3);

    if( code == "*41" ) {

                code2 = blocks[  i+1 ].substr(0,3);

                if( code2 != "*11" ) continue;

                int index = i +1;

                while(code2 == "*11" ) {

                    section.push_back( blocks[ index ] );
                    index++;

                }

                sections.push_back(section);
                section.clear();
                i = index - 1;

    } else continue;

}

return sections;
```

}

Comment: in debug mode go into your function step by step to see where it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of bound indexing where `0 <= i < size`:

```
 blocks [i+1]
```

`i+1` exceeds the valid index where `i=blocks.size()-1`.

Moreover, this loop never finishes:

```
while(code2 == "*11" ) {
   section.push_back( blocks[ index ] );
   index++;
}
```

Comment: I am working with the file. Block represent one row in the file and after a row which begins wit *41 there will always be another row

Comment: @Jefffrey: If control goes to the loop, there is nothing to break the loop or changes the condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
> while(code2 == "*11" ) {
>     section.push_back( blocks[ index ] );
>     index++; }
```

that can never be passed ...

```
i = index - 1;
```

could end in endless loop

Comment: Why it cannot be passed ?

Comment: Oh i see, like i said I am a beginner and I have done something really stupid. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Out of bounds reached when i=blocks.size()-1 for : 
code2 = blocks[  i+1 ].substr(0,3);

Also this is an endless loop :
 while(code2 == "*11" ) {

```
                section.push_back( blocks[ index ] );
                index++; }
```